# In JavaScript, why super keyword is not calling always parent class method for further calls?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, es6-class

Here child class object call `super.msg1()` which means for this call `Parent's msg1()` function should be used.  But what if `Parent's msg1()` calls another function `msg2()` of own class, I means `Parent's msg2()`.

So in that case both direct and indirect calling of function should use the definition of Parent class which is not happening here.

Using `super`, child class wants to complete the execution of any function of `Parent` class method and in current example, calling of `msg2()` is the part of `msg1()` definition. One important thing is that, I don't want to modify the parent class to achieve my expected output.

Take a look to the current output:

```
Message 1 from Parent class
Message 2 from Child class
```

but I was expecting

```
Message 1 from Parent class
Message 2 from Parent class
```

Is there any hidden rule I am missing in inheritance and how can I achieve my expected output ?

```js
class Parent {
    msg1() {
      console.log('Message 1 from Parent class')
      this.msg2();
    }

    msg2() {
      console.log('Message 2 from Parent class')
    }
  }

  class Child extends Parent {

    constructor() {
      super();
    }

    msg1() {
      super.msg1();
    }

    msg2() {
      console.log('Message 2 from Child class')
    }
  }

  ch = new Child();
  ch.msg1();
```

Is there any way to get the expected output here without modifying the parent class.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I nearly did. Your title is very misleading and should be changed. "why super keyword is not calling always parent class method" isn't correct. You also don't do it in the code. You calling `this` and expecting `super` properties from it because it is in the inherited class. As somebody clicking on the title and then getting this description you feel trolled. Please adjust the title.

Comment: I agree, so I changed the title but description is well explanatory and also it does not contains 1k line of code which requires you to scroll from top to bottom to get it.

Answer (score 2):

What you observe is totally expected. See https://javascript.info/class-inheritance

`super` *does always call* the "parent" class methods. But your log `"Message 2 from Child class"` is caused by `this.msg2()` in the parent class. What you don't know or what is strange to you, is that the `this` instance stays the same as in the child class, so the method is also overwritten in the parent class inner method scope. This is totally expected in all object orientated languages.

**Edit:** If you want those properties you have to use a "trick" where you add a additional method with the original functionality, so you can decide in the parent class to call the original functionality or the (possibly) extended one.

```js
class Parent {
    msg1() {
      console.log('Message 1 from Parent class')
      // call basic functionality directly, to avoid use of override method
      this._msg2basic();
    }

    // Redirect call
    msg2(...args) {
      this._msg2(...args)
    }

    // Basic msg2 functionality of the parent that could be needed if overwrite.
    // Usually with a underscore _ to indicate it's private and not intended for "outside" usage.
    _msg2basic() {
      console.log('Message 2 from Parent class')
    }
  }

  class Child extends Parent {

    constructor() {
      super();
    }

    msg1() {
      super.msg1();
    }

    // Override parent msg2
    msg2() {
      console.log('Message 2 from Child class')
    }
  }

  ch = new Child();
  console.log('ch.msg1()')
  ch.msg1();
  console.log('ch.msg2()')
  ch.msg2();
```

Comment: How can I achieve the result which I am expecting. If any function calling is happening in Parent class then I want to use parent class instance because I can not use super inside parent class. Is it possible ?

Comment: Easy, there is a trick, give me a sec to edit my answer

Comment: You are modifying the Parent class which I don't want, if child class we want to achieve it then it is possible to do that without modifying parent class.

Comment: Well, in that case you shouldn't overwrite the msg2 method then, if you cant handle compatibility with the original method functionality. This is not intended in the design of object orientated programming.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your answer. Lets wait for some more answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate exactly what you want to do? I may have a second idea, which is kinda bad code style and doesn't really give you a child class, but maybe still is what you need... Is this `msg2` method the only thing you want to change (or add) to the object? And you can't modify the parent class? It is maybe a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: You just added the information you already told me in this comment section. But I expected an explanation of your use case of this Child and Parent class. What are you indent to do with this, not waht behavior you want. See [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)